# Labeling only points that ends with the number 5 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a shape file with points at evenly spaced intervals, the table has the following fields:
Name  is up to 32 characters of text.  it is currently populated with an eight digit number.

Point_No is an integer field which has the same eight digit number that is in the Name field.

What I would like to do is to only label the points that have the Name field or the Point_No field  which end with the number "5"

I have tried case statements, substr statements, I have tried to use the modulus with the Point_No field, but I keep getting parsing errors.

Answer (score 5):

I'd label the entire layer using whichever field you'd like. Then, in the Labels -> Rendering tab, look for the "Show label" control. Click that button and select "Edit". Enter an expression along the lines of:

```
right( "Point_No", 1 ) = 5
```

This should only display labels for features where Point_No ends with a 5.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest another way to solve your problem. In the "Expression dialog" of the "layer labeling setting" use this expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN  tostring(  "Point_No" ) LIKE '%5' 
THEN  "Point_No"  
END
```